# Bulding on xcode fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gnupg

I'm trying to build the latest version of GPGMail for MacOS Mojave, and within xCode when building the GPGMail module, I get an error in one of the last "Build Phases"

All I simply did was downloaded the source code, and opened it with xcode.
But of what I understand, this has to do with the fact it's being executed under Apple Sandbox.

I've tried disabling the entitlements list, but that had no effect;

Any suggestion?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The build process doesn't run in a sandbox. That script is trying to install GPGMail under `/Users/jamesbednell/Library/Mail/Bundles` but failing.

Try creating that folder manually and then rebuild on Xcode.